# Cmake error - Cmakeoutput error - trying to build APBS program with compiling

Tags: python, cmake, compilation

I am building a program called APBS, I cloned the GitHub repository, and ran `cmake ..` command.
I got the following error in 2 files (`CMakeError.log` and `CMakeOutput.log` files)

errors are:

Missing/invalid rpc/rpc.h header.  XDR support disabled
Call Stack (most recent call first):
externals/fetk/maloc/CMakeLists.txt:49 (header_and_type_checks)

CMake Error at externals/fetk/maloc/src/CMakeLists.txt:40 (install):
install FILES given no DESTINATION!

Comment: Content of files `CMakeError.log` and `CMakeOutput.log` is meaningless without the **error message** you found in **output**, **before** the line `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

Comment: yes, i edited the question.

Comment: The error message is somewhere else (above). The line "-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" just states that the error has been occurred.

Comment: yes, i included the errors

Comment: The message with "Missing/invalid rpc/rpc.h header" is just a **warning**, it doesn't prevent the project from being built. The **actual error message** is `install FILES given no DESTINATION!`. It is because the project never defines a variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR`, which value is used: https://github.com/Electrostatics/FETK/blob/0fe0adb34b815a0866f1ed2d3886936f3bae9c69/maloc/src/CMakeLists.txt#L40. There are two calls `include(GNUInstallDirs)`: https://github.com/Electrostatics/apbs/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L65, but both of them are commented out. Report the problem to the developers